# How can I parse XML to get multiple text blocks with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

I want to parse some XML that looks like this:

```
<node>
  This is
  <child>
    blah
  </child>
  some
  <child>
    foo
  </child>
  text
</node>
```

How do I get access to the text node children in Simple XML?

Can I access them in the correct order of text and element children?

Do I need some other package for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend switching to the [DOM functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) over SimpleXML. I had an answer like this a while ago [which wasn't very popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565/what-xml-parser-do-you-use-for-php/68615#68615), but I still stand by it. The DOM functions are just so much powerful: the extra verbosity is worth it.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xmlString);

foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $node) {
    if ($node->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE) {
        echo $node->nodeValue . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You get my upvote on that question. I'm scratching my head. People don't know that's valid XML? WTF?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($this->xml->xpath('/node/child') as $child){
   ...
}
```

Comment: @Jayrox, It returns the <child> nodes but not the requested "This is", "some", and "text" nodes.

Comment: Yeah it's those text nodes that I want, in the correct order with the child elements. Child elements are easy: foreach ($xml->children() as $child) { ... }