# Getting texts as child nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

This is my XML:

```
<form action="">
    test
    <optionbox>
        <h3>This is an option box</h3>
    </optionbox>
    last text
</form>
```

Now, I'm using `SimpleXML` to parse the XML. I expected `$root->children()` to return 3 elements and with the exact following order:
`test (text)`,`<optionbox>`,`last text (text)` but it only returns the `<optionbox>` element. If I use `__toString` it correctly returns full text so the XML file is parsed correctly.

How can I make it parse also texts as `SimpleXMLElement` objects just like it does for XML tags?

Comment: An element only has one text node, thus "test\n last text" is the text node for the <form> element

Comment: @Scuzzy: Oh I don't think so; because the ordering of these elements is pretty much important. (As it matters in HTML)

Comment: Then perhaps SimpleXML is not the tool for the task and you will have to venture over to the DOMDocument class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664202/how-can-i-parse-xml-to-get-multiple-text-blocks-with-simplexml The accepted answer in this thread performs what you're seeking.

Comment: Thanks, I think this will workaround the problem ;)