# I need to get xml with php. How would I go about that?

Tags: php, xml

What is the best way?

Comment: Near duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/68565/what-xml-parser-do-you-use-for-php

Comment: There is no *best* way. It depends on your UseCase.

Comment: Seriously, a 5-word question?

Answer (score 2):

[SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) and the [PHP DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) are good bets.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**SimpleXML**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php). It turns an XML document into an object that provides **structured access** to the XML.

To create a SimpleXML object from an XML document stored in a `string`, pass the string to `simplexml_load_string`( ). It returns a SimpleXML object.

As an example consider this:

```
$channel =<<<_XML_
<channel>    
 <title>Example title</title>    
 <link>http://example.com/</link>    
 <description>Example desccription</description>    
</channel>    
_XML_;
// The XML that needs to be parsed

$xml = simplexml_load_string($channel); // create a SimpleXML object.

print "The $xml->title channel is available at $xml->link. ";
```

will print:

```
The Example title is available at http://example.com/.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following program also for creating the SimpleXml object.
Using SimpleXml object you can access the xml tags.

test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<employee>

        <name> Shyam </name>
        <age> 20 </age>
        <place> Chennai </place>
</employee>
```

file.php

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml");

echo $xml->getName() . "<br />";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
          {
            echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "<br />";
          }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

By "get XML", do you mean retrieve it from a remote source, or parse a XML text that you already have?

For the former, either use PHP's built-in capability to load URL content (via the file_get_contents or similar functions applied to URLs), or use a library like cURL (which is included standard with most PHP distributions).

For the latter, libraries like [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) (also included standard) can be quite useful.

Comment: First retrieve, then parse. And so that all the process is not error prone.